# UILabel not taking appropriate frame when reloading view

Tags: ios, swift, frame

So the main screen of my app has a hamburger button which can be used to navigate to other parts of the app. That being said, there's a chance someone might get notifications in other parts of the app, so I'm trying to add an indicator, which is just a subclass of `UILabel` which shows up over the hamburger button. When the view first loads, it looks like this, which is fine:

[image]

Okay, so when the user opens the navigation drawer I animate the hamburger button and remove the notification by hiding it (`self.badge.hidden = true`), and it goes away fine, like this:

[image]

Now the problem I'm facing is that when the view is animated back in, the notification badge ends up in a really weird place, even though no frames change, and if I print out the frames, it's exactly where it should be programmatically, but it actuality it ends up looking really weird, as just the tiny bubble in the top left corner:

[image]

All I'm doing to add it back is in my delegate method for when the navigation drawer closes, I try `self.badge.hidden = false`. So obviously there's something weird going on here.

But what's even weirder, is that if I navigate to another view, say I press one of the buttons in the navigation drawer, and then go back to the home view, then the hiding works fine, and when I unhide the notification badge then it appears exactly where it should be! As I said, this only happens if I navigate away from the home screen and then back to it, but when the app first loads and I go to the navigation drawer, then the notification badge gets put in the wrong place and is also very tiny. I've tried a lot of things to try to get this to work. Originally I was reinitializing the badge view before I added it back using the same frame I did when the view loaded, but it still ended up the way it looks now. I also tried to set it to nil and remove it from the `superView` instead of just hiding it, but all of the different things I've tried have resulted in the same thing: only on the home screen before navigating elsewhere, the badge doesn't end up in the right place after closing the navigation drawer. I can post more code or answer any additional questions you might have, but please help me I can't figure this one out!

Here is my initialization code in `viewDidAppear`:

```
    badge = SwiftBadge(frame: CGRectMake(15, -5, 15, 15))
    menuButton.addSubview(badge!)
    menuButton.bringSubviewToFront(badge!)
```

And creating my menuButton (which I do do in `viewDidLoad`)

```
menuButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20))
menuButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Side menu.png"), forState: .Normal)
let addBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: addButton)
let menuButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: menuButton)
self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(menuButtonItem, animated: true)
```

EDIT 2:

Code for rotating the hamburger button

```
let animationDuration = self.revealViewController().toggleAnimationDuration
        UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: { () -> Void in
            if !self.menuButtonRotated {
                //self.badge?.removeFromSuperview()
                self.badge?.hidden = true
                self.menuButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
                self.menuButtonRotated = true
                print("Menu frame after rotation: \(self.menuButton.frame)")
            } else {
                self.menuButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(0))
                self.menuButtonRotated = false
                self.badge?.hidden = false
            }
            }, completion: { (bool) -> Void in
                if !self.menuButtonRotated {
                //self.badge = SwiftBadge(frame: CGRectMake(250, 250, 100, 100))
                print("New menu frame: \(self.menuButton.frame)")
                print("New badge frame: \(self.badge!.frame)")
                //self.view.addSubview(self.badge!)
                //self.badge?.hidden = false
            }
    })
```

Commented out code is some other things I've tried.

Comment: Are you styling in viewDidLoad? And is it the root ViewController? At that point the root ViewController doesn't have it's correct frame yet.

Comment: Originally I was doing the styling in `viewDidLoad` but then I put it in `viewDidAppear` for the exact reason you mentioned, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Even then it might not always work. Have you tried styling it in the second VC? Does it give a different frame?

Comment: You mean have I tried to do this in another view in my app? No I was trying to resolve the issue here first haha

Comment: Is your indicator label a subview of the button or the button's superview?

Comment: @MikeAtNobel it is a subview. As you can see in my edited question I showed how I originally create the view, and then add it to my button.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. Have you considered making a custom button that subclasses UIView and that contains a button and a label?

Comment: No I hadn't but since it has erratic behavior where it works fine if I navigate away from the home screen and then back to it, I don't know if this will resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm not too sure if it would either, but I think adding a subview to a UIButton, while technically allowed since it is a UIView, might cause odd behavior since buttons aren't really designed to for laying out subviews. So maybe removing the label from the button would provide more stable results. Maybe.

Comment: I just can't comprehend why this would work fine after navigating away from the first screen, but not when I'm just switching between the navigation drawer and the current view. It doesn't make sense to me!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94652/discussion-between-mikeatnobel-and-pbush25).

Comment: How are you rotating the hamburger button? Can we see that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after much debugging and hair pulling, I finally figured out what the fix was. For whatever reason it seems that my `menuButton` frame wasn't set as soon as the animation ended, so I had to change my animation code to below, hopefully this will help someone who comes looking later:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: { () -> Void in
            if !self.menuButtonRotated {
                self.badge?.hidden = true
                self.badge?.removeFromSuperview()
                self.badge = nil
                self.menuButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
                self.menuButtonRotated = true
                print("Menu frame after rotation: \(self.menuButton.frame)")
            } else {
                self.menuButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(0))
                self.menuButtonRotated = false
            }
            }, completion: { (bool) -> Void in
                if !self.menuButtonRotated {
                    print("New menu frame: \(self.menuButton.frame)")
                    print("New badge frame: \(self.badge?.frame)")
                    let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.05 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
                    dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.badge = SwiftBadge(frame: CGRectMake(13, -7, 15, 15))
                        self.badge?.alpha = 0.95
                        self.menuButton.addSubview(self.badge!)
                        self.menuButton.layoutIfNeeded()
                    }
            }
})
```